# How to setup jQuery cookie plugin in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Is the same as installing any other wordpress plugins?

Answer (score 4):

I'd supplement saibot's answer by saying that, instead of a raw `<script>...</script>` block, you should [use `wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_script_from_your_theme.2C_excluding_admin_area) also when including the plugin script:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery-cookie", get_bloginfo('template_url').'/jquery.cookie.js', array(), '0'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really, you kind of have to go through the back door a little.

First off, make sure you're including jQuery the 'right' way (WP includes a copy):

```
 <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

In the header, include the plugin script the way you normally would, eg,

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='source/script.js'></script>
```

And then when you are writing your script, make sure it's in no-conflict mode:

```
 (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
       //Scripts go in here!
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

And then stick the actual script inside the jQuery no-conflict wrapper.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

And to make sure you're including jQuery, i'd supplement to Jani's answer:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery-cookie", get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path/to/jquery.cookie.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0'); ?>
```

[`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) would be just in case your script is located in a child-theme

Old thread i know, just wanted to share as it got me stuck for some time... until i added that 'jquery' in the array.