# How to process JS & PHP Script in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, dialog

**Problem:**
The script listed below will only run if it's listed out on the page. If its enqueued then it fails. I assume this is because if its enqueued then the php is NOT processed, but I don't know enough to be sure.

**Question**
Is there any way to call the script or is it just a fundamental requirement that any script containing php has to be listed on the page?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#buttonLink').dialog({autoOpen: false});
var readerStatus="<?php echo $_COOKIE['readerStatus'];?>";

if (readerStatus=="tester")  
    {
    jQuery("#buttonLink").dialog('open');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you replace <?php echo $_COOKIE['readerStatus'];?> with tester ans put it inside the page?

Comment: I think in javascript, you can read the cookies as well, you do not need PHP for that.

Comment: Hakre it's about when the cookies are set, and which data can be read from which cookie due to the output buffer. Dorich's example only shows JavaScript trying to access that cookie, but what if another PHP script needs to access it as well? I believe it would be much easier and more scalable - especially in an MVC environment - to have PHP exclusively handle all temporary data storage and retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use PHP to read cookies, you can do this with javascript instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * taken from
     *   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp 
     * but instead you can opt for the jquery cookie
     * plugin, see
     *    http://stackoverflow.com/q/2148695/367456
     */
    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#buttonLink').dialog({autoOpen: false});
        var readerStatus=getCookie('readerStatus');

        if (readerStatus && readerStatus=="tester")  
        {
            jQuery("#buttonLink").dialog('open');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, I didn't know that cookies could be read in Javascript so this is really helpful. Unfortunately it seems there is some other problem that I've created because whether I use the php approach or the approach you suggested the scripts fails in FF & Safari. So I have to assume that there is a flaw in my approach and it needs more research.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your external javascript file like common.js.php and have php output the data as javascript. Then you can include whatever PHP variables you need inside your script.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
?>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#buttonLink').dialog({autoOpen: false});
var readerStatus="<?php echo $_COOKIE['readerStatus'];?>";

if (readerStatus=="tester")  
    {
    jQuery("#buttonLink").dialog('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem may be deeper that I suspected. After more experiments I'm finding that the original script works in Chrome but will not work in FF or Safari. I added your additional php code but it didn't alter the result, the script still fails in FF and Safari.